# Hide product from Woocommerce Shop page if it has already been purchased

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to hide a product from the Woocommerce shop page. If the logged in user has already purchased said product.

I have already been able to block the user from purchasing again using `woocommerce_is_purchasable`, and `woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable`. But I would like to hide it all together not even shown to them in the shop page. I have been coming up empty on this one. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this hide for all users or only for the current user?

Comment: Need to hide for the logged in user, if they have purchased the product already. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the product query using the `pre_get_posts` action hook and then you can get current user products that they already purchased. pass all products id to `post__not_in`. check the below code. code will go active theme function.php file.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased', 20 );

function hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased( $query ) {
   
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;
   
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;
       
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' ),
        ) );
       
        if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
        
        $product_ids = array();
        
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
            if( $order ){
                $items = $order->get_items();
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    $product_id    = $item->get_product_id();
                    $product_ids[] = $product_id;
                }
            }
        }

        $product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $product_ids );
    }

}
```

Comment: it almost worked out of the box. I had to change 'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'completed' ), to wc-completed. Thanks again!. I will mark as accepted. Maybe you want to make that edit for others who find this answer?

Comment: Welcome... Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bhautik's answer is technically correct based on the question asked. Hide product if user bought before.

However as mentioned in my question I'm already disabling purchase of said products using `woocommerce_is_purchasable` .

Meaning the logic of what should be hidden is already in the software. Using his idea as a template I have made the answer more generic to operate off of `woocommerce_is_purchasable` . Meaning I only have to implement any conditional logic in that function and the shop will reflect by hiding said products (that are not purchasable).

I am posting this as a second answer in case it helps others searching this problem. But will keep his as the selected answer to the question.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased', 20 );

function hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased( $query ) {
  //Get all the products in the store.
  $products = wc_get_products(['limit' => -1]);

  //Blank exclusion array. 
  $product_ids = array();

  //Check each product to see if it is purchasable or not.
  foreach($products as $product){
    if(!$product->is_purchasable()){
      //If product is not purchasable then add to exclusion array.
      $product_ids[] = $product->get_id();
    }
  }
    //Use array of id's to exclude products in the shop page.
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $product_ids );
}
```